# Convert file to Gzip memory stream, then convert that to Base64 before exporting to text file (or var)

Tags: powershell, gzip, gzipstream

How do I change the below so i can use the Gzip data with [System.Convert]::ToBase64String() **instead of an outfile** then send THAT output(the b64) to an outfile

**I Received these answers from help on a previous post from an awesome member. It was marked as an answer but my goals were misunderstood.

Right now this does **INFILE>Compress>OUTFILE**, I want to do **INFILE>Compress>Convert>OUTBase64**

```
$infile = Get-Item path\to\myfiletocompress.ext
$instream = $infile.OpenRead()
$outstream = (New-Item path\to\mygzfile.gz).OpenWrite()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
$instream.CopyTo($gzip)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()
$instream.Dispose()
```

And with this the reverse, I want to use Base64 for the input from a Var, and have that get converted from base64 first then get decompressed into an outfile.

This is currently **INFILE>Decompress>OUTFILE** I would like to **INBase64>Convert>Decompress>OUTFILE**

```
$infile = Get-Item path\to\mygzfile.gz
$instream = $infile.OpenRead()
$outstream = (New-Item path\to\myexpandedgzfile.ext -Force).OpenWrite()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $instream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
$gzip.CopyTo($outstream)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()
$instream.Dispose()
```

The way I'm doing it now is with no compression, using IO.File ReadAllBytes, WriteAllBytes.

File>B64

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('anyfile.ext')) | Out-File 'anyfile.txt"
```

B64>File

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('anyfile.ext', [Convert]::FromBase64String('anyfile.txt'))
```

I tested the results of using gzip files instead of originals when encoding to B64 and the B64 encoded files were smaller than the originals, so this would be worth it.

---

**EDIT**: Using the below code with a temp file I can get a working result:

```
$filename = 'reflect_setup_free_x64.exe'
$infile = Get-Item $filename
$instream = $infile.OpenRead()
$outstream = (New-Item "$filename.gz").OpenWrite()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
$instream.CopyTo($gzip)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()
$instream.Dispose()
[Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$filename.gz")) | SC "$filename-encoded.txt" -NoNewline
```

But using the updated code in the solution gives me a larger file by min ~20%, something is wrong with it. Fails on decompression as well:

```
$content = Get-Content 'reflect_setup_free_x64.exe' -Raw
$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content)
$gzip.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$gzip.Dispose()

# This is the b64 gzip string
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($outstream.ToArray()) | SC 'reflectencoded.txt'
$outstream.Dispose()
```

---

And lasty I'm stuck on the reverse command to recreate the file from b64 ->->. This works with a temp file can you show me how to add the stream to this as well? Normally I can pick apart the answers and context to proceed on my own, but i do not understand this yet..

```
$filename ='reflect_setup_free_x64.exe'
$encoded = GC "$filename-encoded.txt"
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$filename.gz", [Convert]::FromBase64String($encoded))
$infile = Get-Item "$filename.gz"
$instream = $infile.OpenRead()
$outstream = (New-Item "$filename" -Force).OpenWrite()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $instream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
$gzip.CopyTo($outstream)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()
$instream.Dispose()
```

---

LAST EDIT - For the reverse process the below was used:

```
$filename ='reflect_setup_free_x64.exe'
$encoded = GC "$filename-encoded.txt"
$instream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new(
[Convert]::FromBase64String($encoded)
)
$outstream = (New-Item "$filename" -Force).OpenWrite()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $instream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
$gzip.CopyTo($outstream)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()
$instream.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream`.

- For a plain text file or hardcoded string:

```bash
# `$content` could also be a hardcoded string here
$content = Get-Content path\to\file.txt -Raw
$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content)
$gzip.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()

# This is the b64 gzip string
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($outstream.ToArray())
```

- For a binary:

```bash
$filename = 'reflect_setup_free_x64.exe'
$infile = Get-Item $filename
$instream = $infile.OpenRead()
$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$gzip = [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal)
$instream.CopyTo($gzip)

$gzip.Dispose()
$outstream.Dispose()
$instream.Dispose()

[Convert]::ToBase64String($outstream.ToArray()) |
    Set-Content "$filename-encoded.txt" -NoNewline
```

You need to ensure that you will be using the same encoding to read this file back, as explained in previous answer, storing a gzip b64 string in a file (specially if it is a binary) doesn't make sense, **`[Convert]::ToBase64String(..)` should be out of this equation. Gzip b64 is mainly used for transport of data not for storage.**

---

As aside, this process can be greatly simplified using the [`PSCompression` Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression) (***Disclaimer:*** *I'm the maintainer of this Module*).

Using the module the first example translates to:

```bash
Get-Content path\to\file.txt -Raw | ConvertTo-GzipString
```

And the second example translates to:

```bash
$filename = Convert-Path 'reflect_setup_free_x64.exe'
$gzPath = $filename + '.gz'
Compress-GzipArchive $filename -Destination $gzPath
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($gzPath)) |
    Set-Content "$filename-encoded.txt" -NoNewline
```

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp if you have doubts about how this is handled you can check the github repo I posted in my previous answer. Right now it's written in c# but if you check previous releases it was all in PowerShell and it covers any imaginable possibility for gzip compression and expansion

Comment: Updated the bottom of OP, something isnt working right the output is larger than if I do the steps one at a time and it wont decompress..

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp thats because you're trying to use an encoding to read a binary. see edit

Comment: Is there a good reason not to just use binary for everything? The binary file (any filetype) option was what I needed but didnt ask for correctly on both posts, maybe my examples made it confusing. THANK YOU VERY MUCH THIS WAS THE PERFECT ANSWER

Comment: Also I added one final question to the OP (It is really the original question) I do not understand this yet. Just showing me how to change the (newly edited) last bit of code on the bottom of the OP to use a stream instead of temp file when doing the b64>binaryfile export process... Is it $instream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new() ?I'm kind of brute forcing my testing with lack of knowledge. I usually have success with my testing methods but not with this, The import method you showed me works great ;P

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp for reading a gzip b64 string you have the example from my previous answer the one that uses the `StreamReader`. For reading a binay that was encoded and compressed you can't obv since a binary is just that bytes

Comment: So there is no way to do the reverse? I can input from exe>compress in memory>save to b64 text.. But its not possible to go B64text>decompressinmemory>output binary or any file?

Comment: bottom of OP is updated. I cant believe I figured out the last part, its so confusing... ;P  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp yes, you can put it back into a new file or read its bytes for sure, in that example from the previous answer for a binary you wouldn't be using a `StreamReader`, `$outmem` would hold the bytes of the file, if you want to put it back into a file you can `$outmem.CopyTo($fileStream)` and then `$fileStream.Dipose()`

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp yup, exactly as you have it in your last edit for the binary works. if it was a plain text then you can change it to use `StreamReader` to read the content